# iOS get absolute time independent of user set time?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, cllocationmanager

I need to be able to get the absolute time the from the iOS device (iPhone 5.0 +)

I used CLLocation timestamp property, but that is not working like I thought it would.

If the user is in an area where the time is 16:45, but for whatever reason the user sets the time manually to 21:00, I want to be able to get the 16:45 time from the device and not the 21:00.

So, how can I get the absolute time from within my app, so that the user has no way to make the app think that it's whatever time he sets in the settings?

EDIT: I am looking to see if there is a way to obtain this without having to ping an external server??

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to query a timeserver on the internet to get time independently of the time the user has set the device to. There are some libraries that may be able to help with this: [ios-ntp](http://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/) and [HS NTP](http://www.hillstone-software.com/hs_ntp_details.htm).

If you're looking for the users localtime, you'll also need to get the users location, and figure out their timezone based on this. And then take care of things like daylight savings/summer time - it's a non-trivial thing to do, as different countries (and states/islands in countries) around the world have their daylight savings switchover at different dates and times.

Comment: Makes sense. I think my question should have been clearer in regards to the fact that I am trying to see if there is a way to obtain that without having to ping some server, so, internally. I wrote the server side for the app and I can easily get that time with a simple API call to it, but is it possible to get it from the phone GPS or simply internally?

Comment: Not that I know of sorry. The time from `[NSDate date]` is the device time. Maybe there are private API methods to access the time from the GPS unit, but I have no clue about those sorry.